# How to get mode for my custom component dynamically in Docusaurus?

Tags: antd, docusaurus

I use a third component Antd to create a menus. The code is

```html
<nav className={clsx(styles.sidebar, 'thin-scrollbar')}>
  <div style={{width: 256}}>
    <Menu mode="inline" theme={"dark"} inlineCollapsed={collapsed}>
      {menus}
    </Menu>
  </div>
</nav>
```

As you can see, Menu has a theme. I would like to get docusaurus's theme mode to fill it. And I hope if I choose light or dark. This parameter can be changed manually.
Antd website is: https://ant.design/components/menu

Current page:

Comment: do you want to pass your current docusaurus theme into this Menu component?